# Strange issue with SharePoint 2013 Search

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-search

I have a strange issue with a search in a SharePoint 2013 site. 
I can find a folder if I type "adams, drew" in a search bar in the document library  - http://screencast.com/t/NVqFj2F0v, but if I type only a word "adams" it returns no results -  http://screencast.com/t/0eMj1eJZAkG

I did not find any crawl errors that may be related to this. Does anybody know why it happens?

Thanks!

Comment: Smells like a bug to me, is this Office 365 or On-premises?

Comment: Did searching for "adams" ever return any results?

Comment: Issues with adams is just an example, we have a lot of other issues similar to this, e.g. if I type "a and a marketing" it returns results, but if I type "marketing" it returns nothing, see screenshots: http://screencast.com/t/BFZ7q91I and http://screencast.com/t/LDxsJ8RbSp74

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried searching for `*marketing*`? I had a similar problem on SharePoint 2010, the search only returned results if you wrote the full text of the property, not a piece of it, then I just had to change some search setting on central admin and it did the trick :)

Comment: Gintas,
strange, *marketing* does not work, but *drew* is working well and I got the results http://screencast.com/t/d7fadjaz

Which setting I need to change in central admin to make it work without *? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution in javascript that adds the wildcard across both sides of the query, but uses it's own textbox and submit button. I'm sure you can "view source" and find the generated HTML object of the search bar id instead of using new controls.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function RedirectUrl()
 {
 var tb = document.getElementById("tbSearch").value;
 if(tb != null)
 {
 window.location.href="?FilterName=Title&FilterMultiValue=*"+tb+"*";
 }
 return false;
 }
 </script>
 <input type="text" id="tbSearch" />
 <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="search" onclick="return RedirectUrl();" />
```

Source: http://sharepoint2ktraining.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_18.html